# offline webcam stream on raspberry pi using motion

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm trying to do webcam (logitech c270) stream on monitor via HDMI. I'm using raspbian and I installed motion (`sudo apt-get install motion`) and i did everything i needed to do. Now when I start motion service, raspberry says it is started successfully and webcam turns on (activity light is on). Where can I see stream from webcam?

Comment: Should be at Port 8081 by default, also have a look at https://motion-project.github.io/motion_config.html#OptDetail_Stream

Answer (score 2):

Start `motion` with:

```
motion -n -c <config-file>
```

where the `<config-file>` is your configuration file for `motion`.
In this config file you can turn on the streaming server that will allow you to access the webcam image stream from the browser.
It should contain the following lines:

```
stream_port 8081
stream_localhost off
webcontrol_port 8080
webcontrol_localhost off
```

Follow the rest of the instructions [for example here](http://rbnrpi.wordpress.com/project-list/setting-up-wireless-motion-detect-cam/).

If you turn on Firefox and go to :8081, you will see the output.
Sadly, for me Chrome is not able to display this stream, but if you make an `html` file like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <img src="http://<ip-address>:8081"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

you should see it in Chrome as well.

Comment: You don't need to do "webcontrol_localhost off" to see the stream.